# Failed "solving environment" for python 3.8 installation through anaconda

Tags: macos, anaconda, python-3.8

```
(base) Apples—MacBook—Pro-2:— sailong$ conda install python=3.8
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: 1 

(base) Apples—MacBook—Pro-2:— sailong$ conda install python=3.8
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: /
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes. Press CTRL—C to abort.
Examining conflict for sqlalchemy pyopenssl conda—package—handling pytest—openfiles pathlib2 py—lief sortedco/ a
```

Did anyone encounter the same problem or knows how to tackle it?
I experience a lot of problems after updating the system.

System: MacOS Catalina V10.15.3

Comment: It has been like such for 30mins, and little overheat of my laptop

Comment: Can you share some information on the environment?

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't use the base environment for development. Create a new environment for each project.

Comment: Yes, I'm using anaconda to install python, which may cause sort of bug

Comment: _I'm using anaconda to install python, which may cause sort of bug_ What do you mean by _which may cause sort of bug_ ?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this problem by uninstall the "whole" python and reinstall with conda. I think the problem maybe due to the other conda python 3.7 package related,

```
conda remove --force
```

Answer (score 0):

These are common Problems when you install Anaconda via the GUI installer, Install Anaconda using the Bash Shell Script from Anaconda.com . This will solve most of the issues.
https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2021.11-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
This one worked for me, use "sudo"